# Digitize video?

Tags: windows, video, encoding, vhs, digitization

I got some movies on a VCR that i want to move to my computer somehow. (for personal use)

I have a video capture card and all hardware required. I'm looking for the software - programs, codecs etc.

I like the format that most torrents come in and got some of these i'd like to use as reference for comparison. How can i see what codec, bitrate, etc a movie is using so i can pick this and know that it will work and look good. For AVI-files the bitrate is visible in explorer but it doesn't mention the codec used and i also have a lot of MKV-files that explorer can't handle.

All kinds of tips, tricks and other suggestions are welcome. This is completely new to me. How do I avoid that video/audio gets out of sync for example, many movies you download have audio out of sync so i guess this can happen quite easily.

The encoding-program has to run on windows and for playback the movies should work on at least VLC for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I recommend you to do for the highest preservation of quality is :

1. Use the application that comes with your capture card.
2. Choose the highest possible resolution and format you can capture (3MBps DV-AVI if possible). (Since you are capturing from VCR, anything above 640 in resolution pixel width will not result in much gain.)
3. Use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert to the desired format. To understand what is the best quality output you should set for your video, you can read this [forum thread here](http://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4474).

Audio/Video sync issues are not a concern nowadays if your source is good, and you keep the in-between conversions between formats to a minimum. In short, just do this :

Capture from Source > Handbrake Conversion

And you will have a very high chance that audio sync issues will not be present.

Comment: I still have problems with audio and video sync, capturing from a mini DV camcorder to disk. VirtualDub loses sync, but WinDV doesn't. Haven't tried Handbrake though.

Comment: +1 Handbrake. I have only add a sync problem once and that was due to me doing another conversion for the ipod at the same time. *PS: Welcome back scoop*

Answer (score 1):

[WinDV](http://windv.mourek.cz/) is an excellent application for capturing video. It will keep your video and audio in sync and doesn't drop frames (remember to disable antivirus when capturing).

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is an old, famous, open-source and still actively-developed video capture/processing software (for Windows only). It is simple and powerful, with lots of features and fine-tuning settings. It's is not a full general-purpose video editor, but I think it might have the exact features you need.